# How can this work (static extension?)

Tags: c#

I saw this in a answer by Marc Gravell, and I just don't see how it would work

```
static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string value)
{    
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
}
```

Shouldn't a call to s.IsNullOrEmpty() where s is null, then return a NullReferenceException?  How can you de-reference the object to call the function defined here if the object is null?

Or is this some way to end-around monkey patching a static function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Extension methods are magic - they only **look** like instance methods, but given the extension method:

```
public static class StaticClass {
    public static void MyMethod(this SomeType obj) // note "this"
    {...}
}
```

then:

```
instance.MyMethod();
```

compiles to:

```
StaticClass.MyMethod(instance);
```

And you wouldn't expect that to throw a `NullReferenceException` - and indeed it doesn't.

This is double-edged. On some levels it is confusing, but it can be really useful. It would be good practice to add your own null-ref check at the start unless you have a *reason* to allow nulls. Another useful one:

```
public static void ThrowIfNull<T>(T value, string name) where T : class {
    if(value==null) throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
}
...
void SomeUnrelatedMethod(string arg) {
    arg.ThrowIfNull("arg");
}
```

Comment: You most probably mean "extension methods" instead of "static methods" in the first sentence...

Comment: d'oh! Indeed. Clarified. Big oops to me.

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods can be called on null values. A call like this:

```
bool x = foo.IsNullOrEmpty();
```

is just translated at compile-time into

```
bool x = ExtensionClass.IsNullOrEmpty(foo);
```

No nullity check is performed implicitly. It's very simple syntactic sugar, basically.

While this is odd when you first see it, it's very handy for tests exactly like this. I also have an extension method I like for parameter validation:

```
x.ThrowIfNull();
```

which throws `ArgumentNullException` if `x` is null.

Comment: The extension methods can only be called on null values if it is not obvious for the compiler that they are null. AFAIK, `((string)null).Extension()` wouldn't compile, so doesn't `default(string).Extension()`.

Comment: @Stefan: I've just tried it, and both of those compile. The latter issues a misleading warning (which is unfortunate) but the first compiles without any problem at all.